# C#, CPCL and getvar

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I am writing a class to print to Zebra bluetooth printers using CPCL. CPCL has a getvar command that you can send to the printer to get printer settings. For example:

```
! U1 getvar "appl.date"
```

This command will return the printer's current date. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the result from this command. I have no problem printing using C# and CPCL since I can just convert the command to a byte array and send it to the printer using a NetworkStream. But I don't know how to actually get results back from commands that should return results. I have confirmed that the command actually returns data using the Zebra Printer Communicator that comes with the printer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things... Make sure you send a `\r\n` after the last `"`. Not sure if WriteLine does that for you, but SGDs need it at the end. Also, you're correct, you need to wait for the printer to return the value before reading it. If you do a read too quickly and the printer has not responded yet, there will be nothing to read.  What you can do is look at the `TcpClient Available` property to see if there are any bytes available before you actually do a read. You can loop and do a quick wait until there are bytes available to read, then you can do the read and make sure there are bytes to read

Answer (score 0):

I found an actual code example here:

https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA140&actp=LIST

The code works fine, the only problem is that it takes a while for the printer to return the data, but the ReadLine executes immediately. This returns an empty string. If you wait for a few seconds and read again, you will get the actual result.